# Deserialize JSON data in to a class in c#

Tags: json, xamarin.forms, json.net

hello people I have this Json data:
https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=6cf59607a32d408eb3e04de1427a3169

and I want to deserialize in the following class

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Divisas2MVVM2.Classes

{
public class ExchangeRates
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "disclaimer")]
    public string Disclaimer { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "license")]
    public string License { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "timestamp")]
    public int TimeStamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "base")]
    public string Base { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "rates")]
    public Rates Rates { get; set; }
}

public class Rates
{
    public double AED { get; set; }
    public double AFN { get; set; }
    public double ALL { get; set; }
    public double AMD { get; set; }
    // I cut the text so that it would not be to long
    public double ZMW { get; set; }
    public double ZWL { get; set; }
}

public class Rate
{
    public double TaxRate { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

this is my attribute

```
 private ExchangeRates exchangeRates;
```

the constructor of my MainViewModel

```
new ObservableCollection data
Rates = new ObservableCollection<Rate>();
```

and in this method a get the json data

```
 try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://openexchangerates.org");
            var url = "/api/latest.json?app_id=6cf59607a32d408eb3e04de1427a3169";
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Message = response.StatusCode.ToString();
                IsRunning = false;
                return;
            }

            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            exchangeRates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExchangeRates>(result);

        }
```

everything works fine, the variable result has correctly the json data in a string format, but when i call JsonConvert . DeserializeObject, the data "rates" it is not assigned correctly, all the other data: disclaimer", "license", "timestamp" etc. is correctly assigned. only rates fail.

[the string is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2CCL.png)

[other data is correct in the class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDbYI.png)

[rates is incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxQDG.png)

sorry for my English I hope you have understood me :)

Comment: What is your question?  The Newtonsoft docs have plenty of examples of how to do this.  Are you encountering an error or exception?  If so, what is it?

Comment: sorry I edit and explained a little more my problem

Comment: Your Model cannot successfully parse the rates data, working on a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this as your model class

```
namespace Rate
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class Rates
    {
        [JsonProperty("disclaimer")]
        public string Disclaimer { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("license")]
        public string License { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
        public long Timestamp { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("base")]
        public string Base { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("rates")]
        public Dictionary<string, double> RatesRates { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Rates
    {
        public static Rates FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rates>(json, Rate.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this Rates self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, Rate.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters = {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

Then do this in your class

```
            var data = Rate.Rates.FromJson("jsonresult");


            var  rate = data.RatesRates;
            foreach (var pair in rate)
            {
                string symbol = pair.Key;  //"AED"
                double value = pair.Value; //3.673175,
            }


var time = data.Timestamp;
            var disclaimer = data.Disclaimer;
            var license = data.License;
```

Tested and working

Comment: thank you very much! I'm going to try it at this moment